# How Do I show the Product Description in a Category List (bigcommerce)

Tags: bigcommerce

We are converting a store from prostores to bigcommerce. We need to have the list of products display both the product name and the product description to the user. At present the template shows only the name, image, price etc; but not the product description.

In our snippets files the snippet CategoryProductsItem.html displays the product info:

```
<li class="%%GLOBAL_AlternateClass%%">
    <div class="ProductImage QuickView" data-product="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%">
        %%GLOBAL_ProductThumb%%
    </div>
    <div class="ProductDetails">
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%" class="%%GLOBAL_SearchTrackClass%% pname">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a>
    </div>
    <em class="p-price">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</em>
    <div class="ProductPriceRating">
        <span class="Rating Rating%%GLOBAL_ProductRating%%"><img src="%%GLOBAL_IMG_PATH%%/IcoRating%%GLOBAL_ProductRating%%.png" alt="" style="%%GLOBAL_HideProductRating%%" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductCompareButton" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideCompareItems%%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBox" name="compare_product_ids" id="compare_%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%" value="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%" onclick="product_comparison_box_changed(this.checked)" /> <label for="compare_%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%">%%LNG_Compare%%</label> <br />
    </div>
    <div class="ProductActionAdd" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideActionAdd%%;">
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductURL%%" class="btn Small icon-%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" title="%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%">%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%</a>
    </div>
</li>​
```

We have tried to modify this by adding the tag %%GLOBAL_ProductDescription%% but it does not return any value for some reason.

How can we pull the product description into the category list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered the answer to this.

The bigcommerce theme that we are using (and others I guess) has two display options for the catalog - under "Store Settings > Category Settings" - on our template they are "Show as a grid" and "Show as a list".

If you choose the "Show as a grid" then the product description isn't passed in to the template snippet that displays the products (CategoryProductsItem.html).

However, If you choose the "Show as a list" then the product description is displayed and is available in the snippet "CategoryProductsItemList.html" as %%GLOBAL_ProductDescription%%

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

The GLOBAL values do not work on pages other than the ones where you find them.  Kinda confusing because they are called GLOBAL, but I believe BC uses that terminology for a different reason than we may have assumed.  In order for this to be made possible, you would have to edit some PHP from the backend, however, on BigCommerce as far as I know, clients do not have access to root, so the PHP cannot be altered.

Here is a list of [BigCommerce Store-wide Variables](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/variables).  Unfortunately, the ones you require are not on that list.

Also, BigCommerce used to be Interspire, which is the same e-Commerce shopping cart software except it was not hosted by the company.  [Here on this thread](https://www.interspire.com/forum/showthread.php?t=14722), I found Interspire clients looking to solve this same problem for themselves, and they succeed.  The difference is that with Interspire, they were able to access root and edit PHP files.

I've also called BigCommerce and they have confirmed this.  If you find info to the contrary, please share.

Comment: Thanks ... I contacted bigcommerce (chat line) and they said that their theme 'athletic' was supposed to do it, and cited this site http://www.zombiesrus.mybigcommerce.com/antique-rugs/ as an example. When we looked at the theme in their demo it doesn't seem to do that though (the demo has no product description in the category listing) ... and so we're a bit leary of paying for the template only to find out that it doesn't work!

Comment: @user1104799 - I am not giving up on this and come Monday morning, I will be working out a javascript method for this.  I've already developed several JS-enabled features for the category listing, and you can see them [here](http://andredevelopment.mybigcommerce.com/) as I develop them.  For example, if you go to "Category" page "Glass Water Pipes" you'll see I've developed a way to pull in a trigger for a video product demo that appears over the category product listing image. I will use a similar method to do what you're looking for and share it when I have it.

Comment: JavaScript shouldn't be necessary in this case. We set our site configuration to show categories as a list, instead of as a grid, and in that case the product description is displayed just fine.

Comment: Oh I see, that's a bit of a pain but it works.  And if you still wanted the list to look like a grid, you could just amend the CSS.  I stick by my answer though because though in this case you can select an option and it works as a solution, in general, on BigCommerce, if you try to use a %%GLOBAL_value%% in some way than it is enabled in the backend PHP to which we have no access, the global value won't work.  A big limitation and a pain.  Glad you found a solution though, props!

Answer (score 0):

The variable is called:         `%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%` 
Not `%%GLOBAL_ProductDescription%%`

Comment: THanks , but I should have mentioned that I had tried that as well, but it doesn't return anything either ... it looks like these globals aren't defined when your in a category listing (seems odd that though)